# Cannot run program "mips64el-linux-android-strip":error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I tried to build a project that developed in Linux, on my Mac, after getting dependencies and other things, I got this error on `Run Tasks` section of the building:

```
Cannot run program "/Users/invisible/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip" (in directory "/Users/invisible/bale/anbe/android-sdk"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I checked the directory and got that `mips64el-linux-android-4.9` folder is empty and a file is there named `NOTICE-MIPS64` that contained this text:

```
This mips64el-linux-android-4.9 directory exists to make the NDK compatible with the Android
SDK's Gradle plugin, version 3.0.1 and earlier, which expects the NDK
to have a MIPS64 toolchain directory.
```

So as I got the point, MIPS isn't supported anymore, so I added:

```
ndk {
       abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
}
```

to my `build.gradle` file, but the problem still remained.

I don't support MIPS in my project, and it seems it's because of the dependencies that this problem occurred. Now I don't know what should I do to solve this problem and get free of this error.

I'm on `Android Studio 3.1.3` and `NDK 17.1.48`.

Comment: Did you try upgrading your gradle plugin version? I think some of the gradle plugin bugs were actually fixed in 3.1 rather than 3.0.1 like that file says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem by using `android-ndk-r11c` instead of `android-ndk-r17b` downloaded [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases).
It seems the problem occurred for using some of the Telegram libraries that used some C libs like `ffmpeg`.

I tried many ways, by setting

```
ndk {
       abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
}
```

In every `build.gradle` file of dependencies that got the error, that changed errors to `jni tasks` and that cause some C deprecation problems and I had to write some CMakeFiles. But finally changing to `ndk 11` and rebuilding works for me.

Comment: `ndk-11` is really too old for recent Android native development. Maybe you should consider upgrade you native build system to newer version of NDK.

Comment: @shizhen Yeah it's too old but I can't get build as I said with newer versions of ndk :(

Comment: You don't need to go all the way back to r11 for mips support. r16 is far enough.

Comment: @DanAlbert No, r16 didn't work for me, I tried all of the versions from r17 to r11 and only r11 worked.

Comment: With different errors, presumably. The mips toolchains were not removed until r17.

Comment: @DanAlbert Yeah with another error about a deprecated part of the code.

Comment: This answer is misleading then. People do not need to revert to r11 to solve the problem stated in the question, and doing so can introduce other issues. I'd recommend posting another question if you couldn't sort out how to build with r16.

Answer (score -1):

Use a virtual box and try to recreate the older version for the operating system you used to create that application.